# Show Editing template on click in Ember

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

I have a list of names in my template

index.handlebars.js.coffee

```
<ul>
    {{#each income in controller}}
      <li {{action editIncome}}>{{income.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>

{{#if isEdited}}
  // I want to edit clicked element here
{{else}}
  {{view EmberMoney.NewIncomeView}}
{{/if}}
```

incomes_controller.js.coffee

```
EmberMoney.IncomesIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend

  isEdited: false

  addIncome: ->
    EmberMoney.Income.createRecord(name: @get('newIncomeName'))
    @get('store').commit()
    @set('newIncomeName', "")

  editIncome: ->
    this.set('isEdited', true)
```

router.js.coffee

```
EmberMoney.Router.reopen
  location: 'history'

EmberMoney.Router.map ->
  @resource 'incomes', ->

EmberMoney.IncomesIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> 
    EmberMoney.Income.find()
```

I wan't to render edit template on this page when i click on each name.
So if i click the name "Kate" under the list it will generate a template of editing this record.

I can't understand how to do this. Thanks for help.

UPD: My problem is the i can't understand how to know the edited object id in place where i want to edit element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to handle your states in your routes.

```
EmberMoney.Router.map ->
  @resource 'incomes', ->
    @route 'index' # this route is used for creating new records
    @route 'edit', { path: '/:income_id/edit' } # this route is used to edit a record

EmberMoney.IncomesRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> 
    EmberMoney.Income.find()

EmberMoney.IncomesEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend

  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    if model.get('transaction') == @get('store').get('defaultTransaction')
      transaction = @get('store').transaction()
      transaction.add model
    controller.set('content', model)

  deactivate: ->
    @modelFor('incomes.edit').get('transaction').rollback()

  events: 
    submit: (record) ->
      record.one 'didUpdateRecord', =>
        @transitionTo 'index'
      record.get('transaction').commit()
```

Now place your template in `incomes.handlebars`, instead of `index`

```
<ul>
    {{#each income in controller}}
      <li>{{#linkTo "incomes.edit" income}} {{income.name}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
{{outlet}}
```

And then in `incomes/index`:

```
{{view EmberMoney.NewIncomeView}}
```

And in `incomes/edit`:

```
<form {{action submit content on="submit"}}>
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=name}}
</form>
```

The advantage here is now you have stored your state in the route.  Also, you can control your events inside each route/state.

I did not include logic for the `IncomesIndexRoute` which should manage creating new records.  But I suppose you can follow a similar logic to the `edit` route.

Finally you should be able to delete `IncomesIndexController` if you manage to handle everything in the routes.

Comment: That changes a lot, I'd advise you to make these states (new & edit) routable.  Add your routes to the question, and I'll help you fix them.

Comment: i added routes to my questions. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer, if you manage to store states in routes instead of controllers, you will find it very rewarding.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I'll try to implement it now.

Comment: I think it should be {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=name}} in edit.handlebars. Is it so?

Comment: i've got a Error: assertion failed: Models cannot belong to more than one transaction at a time  when i click on the link the same time. I haven't got ideas why. Can you help me more?

Comment: no errors at all. Thanks a lot. Where can i search information of fixing such errors? I found nothing in google.

Comment: Ember.js is fairly new, so you might not find answers to all errors on Google.  On the bright side, the errors are pretty self explanatory; from "Models cannot belong to more than one transaction at a time" you can deduce that the model is being added to more than one transaction... look in the code where you're adding the model to a transaction, and make sure it doesn't get added twice...